# Time how long a service call takes to gather its response

Tags: javascript, function, time, service, call

I'm looking to time how long several service calls take to gather the response and set it in a variable. For instance, in a call like so:

`response = svc.call.someService()`

I could surround in with date calls like so:

```
var start = new Date.getTime();
response = svc.call.someService();
var end = new Date.getTime();
var time = end - start;
```

But I need to do this with several service calls throughout my code and would like to somehow make a function that could do this for me but keep the response variable the way it is. I can't alter the service itself either. Any ideas on an elegant way to gather how long the service call takes?

Comment: By "service call" I assume you mean an `XMLHttpRequest`?

Comment: It's a proprietary service call. Not XMLHttpRequest. If it was I would be able to add an event listener or something I believe, but I don't think this is the case here.

Comment: Make a wrapper function for your service call routine that includes the timing code, see also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance

Comment: wrapper function works well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a wrapper function that does exactly what you've suggested, and just pass server call references to it as a parameter, like this....

```
function timeServiceCall(serviceCall) {
    var start = new Date.getTime();
    var response = serviceCall();
    var end = new Date.getTime();
    console.log("time taken = " + end - start);
    return response;
}
```

Then you just call the service call like so...

```
var response = timeServiceCall(svc.call.someService);
```

Comment: Nice! I'm new to Javascript so I forgot about callbacks. Thanks for the idea that should work well.

Comment: No worries - glad to help :)

Comment: Incidentally, I'd recommend having a look at this... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/time  It's great for helping debug performance issues.

Answer (score 1):

Make a wrapper function, like so:

```
function time (callback) {
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    var result = callback.call();
    return [result, new Date().getTime() - start];
}
```

Then use like so:

```
var called = time(svc.call.someService);
var result = called[0];
var timeTaken = called[1];
```